# How to create a Listview which refreshes along with scrolling in android?

Tags: android, listview, dynamic, android-volley

I want to create a ListView which gets information from a database using VOLLEY. I want to call the Volley in a loop which will allow the data to come one by one. Is there any way to make a ListView which adds items whenever volley gets a item returned from the database?

Comment: you add items to an `Adapter` (for example to `ArrayAdapter`), not to a `ListView`

Answer (score 0):

You can use some libraries way cooler to top your ListView from android-arsenal.com . here is a list of libraries that are even new https://android-arsenal.com/tag/78?sort=created

You can see a detailed video by Vivz from Slidenerd [Pull to refresh tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2lcBx4KVUVk)

Answer (score 0):

Add items to your item set, and simply notify the adapter (`adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`) that items been changed.

If you going to insert them one by one you might want to look into [RecyclerView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html#notifyItemInserted(int)) and use its notify methods like `notifyItemInserted`. It is specially designed for that and comes with animations to represents an item being inserted/updated/moved/deleted.